# Dotnet build fails but building works in Visual Studio / Slowcheetah

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, slowcheetah

In a ASP.NET Core 1.1 (Angular SPA Template) I added slowcheetah to use the json transforms on appsettings.json.

In Visual Studio, starting with debugging works, as well as building and publishing zu Azure.

For working on the SPA, I prefer using Vs Code. Unfortunately building from there, and aswell from the console (`dotnet build`) fails with with error:

> C:\Users\JohnDoe\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.slowcheetah\3.0.61\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets(83,5):
>   error MSB4062: The "TransformTask" task could not be loaded from the
>   assembly
>   C:\Users\JohnDoe\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.slowcheetah\3.0.61\build..\tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the
>    declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
>   [d:\path\to\project\MyProject.csproj]

Probably a problem with slowcheetah? https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5457 (comment from piotrpMSFT).

Any idea why this fails and how to fix it?

Many thanks,

Martin

Comment: Discovered this question while looking at https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah/issues/48. 

You really don't need to transform the appsettings.json file you should rather create different json files with the environment name (e.g. appsettings.production.json) and have customized values for that environment there as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects.